# formatNumber : how to add 2 decimal digits at the back of numbers?

Tags: java, grails, string-formatting

I am using grails formatNumber and I would like to display my numbers in decimal format.

I would like to display 10 as 10.00 
or 0 as 0.00 with 2 decimal digits.

how to do that ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that you were looking for how to do this with Grails' [formatNumber](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/formatNumber.html) tag

```
<g:formatNumber number="${10}" format="0.00"/>
<g:formatNumber number="${0}" format="0.00"/>
```

results in

```
10.00
0.00
```

The [formatNumber](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/formatNumber.html) tag uses [DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) for the `format` parameter

Answer (score 5):

Java 5?

```
 String.format("%.2f", (double)value);
```

Java 4?

```
 new BigDecimal(value).scale(2, RoundingMode.ROUND_HALF_UP).toString();
```

(from memory, may contain typos)

Answer (score 3):

Or using the `NumberFormat` way:

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
Assert.assertEquals("10.00", formatter.format(10));
Assert.assertEquals("0.00", formatter.format(0));
Assert.assertEquals("0.10", formatter.format(0.1));
```

Asserting with Junit.

Have a look at the [documentation for `DecimalFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) for how to create the formatting String for the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You should use it as it is described in the grails [docu](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Tags/formatNumber.html)

```
   <g:formatNumber number="${value}" minFractionDigits="2"/>
```